# Easiest way to perform incremental merge in mercurial

Tags: merge, mercurial

I have a project, that have branched sometime. Both branches have had a lot of commits since the split, and I want to merge them into one. Simply merging the two heads is not enough because it has too many conflicts, and the merged branch is also unstable, and non-functional.

Therefore I want to incrementally merge the two branches. By incremental I mean I take the tip of one of the branches and apply the changes from the other one one at a time. Testing each merge, and continuing if everything goes well.

What is the easiest way to do this using mercurial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've pretty much outlined a strategy yourself. Assume you have two heads, named headA and headB. `hg up -r headB` to one of the two heads, then use `hg merge -r X` repeatedly, where X is a revision along the other line of development.

You can use `hg log -r 'ancestor(headA,headB)::headA'` to get a list of good candidates for these merges (depending on overall topology).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hg transplant](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) to pull specific changesets into a branch.

Comment: The drawback here is you end up with the same change in your repo twice with two different hashids.  Merge is always preferable to transplant when it's possible.